# RewriteRule returns Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get the hang of Rewrite rules. I've used some generators and guides to try and understand how it works, and the code I get back is the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule view_image/img/(.*)/ view_image.php?img=$1
RewriteRule view_image/img/(.*) view_image.php?img=$1
```

**I'm trying to re-direct:**
http://www.danielfew.uk/projects/file_upload/view_image.php?img=food-q-c-1920-1080-2.jpg

**To:**
http://www.danielfew.uk/projects/file_upload/view_image/img/food-q-c-1920-1080-2.jpg/

**Or even better, redirect:**
http://www.danielfew.uk/projects/file_upload/view_image.php?img={image-name}

**To:**
http://www.danielfew.uk/img/{image-name}

Or thats what the generator say's... but each time I goto that page I get an Internal Server Error.

Can someone give me a hand and help me understand how Rewriting URL's work?

I have removed the content of .htaccess for now so you can view the page without getting Internal Server Error.

Comment: What internal server error are you getting?  Is it a PHP error (have you checked the PHP logs)?  Or a redirect?  Or what?

Comment: You also may want to add the L flag to each statement (prevents further processing), as `[L]`.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: @Daniel Few: Yes, I acn help you, but do you need generators ?

Comment: @Daniel Few: Please reply fast!

Comment: @Softbazz maybe he's checking his logs or something. Relax it's been a couple of minutes.  Daniel Where is your .htaccess file located and did you  check your apache error_log?

Comment: Hi, I think if it was explained I would understand, I've done some reading up on it. I only used generators to see if it worked.

Comment: @PanamaJack: Ok, sorry, because of that: I am on pressure

Comment: Softbazz, thanks for responding as your in a rush. What do you mean by do I need generators?

Comment: @DanielFew: .htaccess generators

Comment: I've put that back in .htaccess and gone to : http://www.danielfew.uk/projects/file_upload/view_image.php?img=food-q-c-1920-1080-2.jpg

This is in my log file:
81.149.182.92 - - [26/Jun/2015:19:42:19 +0100] "GET /projects/file_upload/view_image.php?img=food-q-c-1920-1080-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 804 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"

Comment: @DanielFew: like view_image.php?img=$1, view_image.php?img=$2 view_image.php?img=$3, view_image.php?img=$4

Comment: @Softbazz I'm very new to redirect, I only used the generator because I wanted to make sure I was doing it right and that rewrite would work if done correctly. But I couldn't even get a simple one to work.

Comment: @DanielFew: do you have the code

Comment: @DanielFew: I was just make for you some thing

Comment: This is what I initially tried to use:


RewriteRule ^img/([^/]*)\.html$ /projects/file_upload/view_image.php?img=$1 [L]

Comment: It say's that should redirect **http://www.danielfew.uk/projects/file_upload/view_image.php?img=food-q-c-1920-1080-2.jpg** to **http://www.danielfew.uk/img/food-q-c-1920-1080-2.jpg.html**

Comment: @DanielFew: YES plz wait

Comment: @DanielFew: ok I just make this: This is the real file http://test.softbazz.com/DanielFew/index.php?id=3
AND this will be the link http://test.softbazz.com/DanielFew/Daniel-Few/

Comment: @DanielFew: Sorry I can not modify directory location name like /DanielFew/Daniel-Few   to /Daniel-Few

Comment: @DanielFew: http://test.softbazz.com/danielfew/DanielFew/3/   This all I can do for you

Comment: Hi Softbazz, can I take a look at the .htaccess settings you used to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is your solution,

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^img/([0-9]+)/?$    view_image.php?img=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

You like must be like that: http://www.danielfew.uk/projects/file_upload/view_image/img/{number}/

NOTE: you can not use name here because this codes not support name, only id={number} ok

Here is demo of my testing site, this is my .htaccess codes

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^DanielFew/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

and my link is this: http://test.softbazz.com/danielfew/danielfew/3/ 
By changing the id number you can see the changes. [danielfew/{id=number}/](http://#)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Sorry for not replying, I'll give this a go and get back to you :)